# Tengo un problema al intentar llenar un select en pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html

llevo rato mirando y corrigiendo pero no encuentra el problema, lo que sucede que le no me sale ningún elemento y creo tener bien código , ha intentado desde otra pagina y también una tablan nueva pero me sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema que es no select siempre aparece vacio, noc si sera problema con la base de datos o algo mas

```html
 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Semillero</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <?php  require'partials/header.php' ?>

   <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
   <p> <?= $message ?></p>
   <?php endif; ?>

    <h1>Semillero</h1>

     <span> or <a href="login.php">Login</a></span>


     <form class="" action="institucion.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="COD_SEM" placeholder="Ingrese el Codigo del semillero">
       <input type="text" name="NOMBRE_SEM" placeholder="Nombre Del Semillero">
       <label>Institucion: </label>
       <select class="" name="INSTITUCION_COD">
         <?php
              require 'database.php';

               $consulta="SELECT * FROM instituciones";
               $ejecutar=mysqli_query($consulta)
          ?>

        <?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opc): ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $opc['codigo_inst'] ?>"><?php echo $opc['nombre_inst']  ?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>


       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Send">

     </form>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En esta línea `<option value="<?php echo $opc['codigo_inst'] ?>"><?php echo $opc['nombre_inst']  ?></option>` te falta agregar el punto y coma `;` al final de cada `echo`. Opcionalmente, puedes reemplazar `php echo` por este símbolo `=`. Así por ejemplo:  `<option value="<?= $opc['codigo_inst']; ?>"><?= $opc['nombre_inst'];  ?></option>`

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiando tu foreach por while, estas accediendo a los datos como un arreglo y posiblemente deberá tratarse como un objeto $opc->codigo_inst
utiliza la función fetch_assoc() para obtener un arreglo

Ejemplo:

```
while ($row = $ejecutar->fetch_assoc()){
 echo '<option value="'.$row['codigo_inst'].' ">'.$row['nombre_inst'].'</option>'
}
```